# How to increase text size of Android ActionBar button?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, text-size

I have two ActionBar buttons: one displaying only an icon, another with no icon - I use text to display the number of new items that app receives. The problem is the text size is way too small, would like to make sth bigger.

Tried styling:

```
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
```

no effect.

Tried loading a custom view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:gravity="fill_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minWidth="64dip"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_refresh" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    style="?android:attr/actionButtonStyle"
    android:text="0" />
```

No success either.

However, I would prefer to maintain style and properties of the ordinary ActionBar button, just increase text size. Is there a way to achieve that? I do not use Sherlock, below is my code for the ActionBar.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
<item 
    android:id="@+id/action_about" 
    android:title="@string/action_about" 
    android:showAsAction="never">        
</item>
<item 
    android:id="@+id/action_counter"  
    android:title="@string/action_counter"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText">
</item>
<item 
    android:id="@+id/action_refresh"  
    android:title="@string/action_refresh"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh" 
    android:showAsAction="always">        
</item>
```

I would like to change text size of the action_counter only.

Answer (score 9):

In your application's base theme, add the following item:

```
<item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/CustomActionBar</item>
```

Then define `CustomActionBar` as follows:

```
<style name="CustomActionBar" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: You should use 20sp instead of 20dp when specifying font size as per Google's recommendations

Comment: I found that under the AppCompat support library I had to use  <item name="actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/CustomActionBar</item>
and inherit from TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu, if this helps anyone.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. I have the actionMenuTextAppearance overriden and linking to a style of mine which is inherited from ActionBar.Menu, without any result

Answer (score -1):

u need to apply style to the action bar.Define some style in style.xml folder.and try to apply for your action bar.